# VBA: copy formula while cells in other Sheet not empty

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to create a sheet where the formulas are copied downwards based on non Empty Cells in Column B.

I have two Sheets in my Excel. For the first I have already written a code to copy all formulas as long as there is Data in Column B.

```
Sub Copy_Formula()
Dim rng As Range

Range("D9:S" & Rows.Count).Clear

Set rng = Range("B8").End(xlDown) 
Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells(8, 18)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(rng.Row, 18))

    With Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(rng.Row, 18))
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I want to perform the similar operation in Sheet2 for cells b5:d5 as long as there are non empty cells in Column B of Sheet1.

So e.g. if I have filled B8:B578 in Sheet1, the formulas in Sheet2 B5:D5 are copied down 570 times.
But I am failing to code the range reference for the different sheets.

This would be a simplified example:

[image: This is my Data in Sheet 1] Sheet 1

[image: Sheet2 before Macro] Sheet 2 before macro

[image: Sheet 2 after Macro] Sheet 2 after macro

So as you can see the cells B5:D5 in Sheet2 were copy and pasted 3 times

Comment: To make your question clear, I suggest you show sample data before and after the result you want. Also, define what you mean by "I am failing to code the range reference for the different sheets"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub Copy_Formula()
rng As long

Range("D9:S" & Rows.Count).Clear

rng = Range("B8").End(xlDown).Row

Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells(8, 18)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(rng, 18))
With Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(rng, 18))
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(5, 4)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(rng - 8 + 5, 4))
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(rng - 8 + 5, 4))
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

...
```

It is what I am understanding from your description... that you already have one line formulated (B5:D5), so it is just a matter to copy this line as it is down the line. I am just keeping your philosophy., the code should be cleaner... so you will not get lost when you are working on between different sheets on a workbook.

```
Sub Copy_Formula()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lng As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
End With

lng = ws1.Range("B8").End(xlDown).Row

ws1.Range("D9:S" & Rows.Count).Clear

ws1.Range("D8:R8").Copy Destination:=ws1.Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(lng, 4))
With ws1.Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(lng, 18))
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With

ws2.Range("B5:D5").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(lng - 8 + 5, 2))
With ws2.Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(lng - 8 + 5, 4))
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes you have understood correctly, the row 8 in sheet 1 and row 5 in Sheet2 are predefied formulas, and i simply want to copy paste row 5 in Sheet 2 as often as there are Data Rows in Sheet 1.
But trying your solutions, I get Run-time error 1004:Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Excel doesnt tell me this -.-

Comment: Whe you run the macro and it stops, then don´t press finish, go for Debug and one line will be highlighted.

Comment: Doesnt work since i get the error as pop up and have to click it away and when im running debug, it  doesnt show any errors

Comment: I already try with your sample and it works for me. Did you check if there is one non blank cell below B8? If it is blank, it can not copy all the units, as it exceed the datasheet dimension. I changed the relative (R1C1) calling to clear it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201029/discussion-between-user11638654-and-david-garcia-bodego).